# OO Mysqli PHP data isn't displaying correctly

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to display information in a table using a while loop but the table wont display anything if there is only 1 result. If there are more than 1, it will display the results -1. For example, for 5 results it will only display 5.

My query is:

```
$queryIndexInvoice = 
"SELECT * 
FROM invoices, clients, users
WHERE invoices.user_id = users.id
AND invoices.client_id = clients.id
AND invoices.estimate = 0
AND invoices.user_id = '$user_id'
AND deleted = 0
ORDER BY invoices.id
DESC LIMIT 5";

$resultIndexInvoice = $connect_db->query($queryIndexInvoice);
$rowIndexInvoice = $resultIndexInvoice->fetch_assoc();
$numIndexInvoice = $resultIndexInvoice->num_rows;
```

and my table is:

```
<tbody>
<?php while ($IndexInvoice = $resultIndexInvoice->fetch_assoc()) {?>    
    <tr class='table_items'>
    <td class='item_strip'></td>
    <th><input type='checkbox'></th>
    <td><?= $IndexEstimate['invoice_id'] ?></td>
    <td><?= $dateIndexEstimate ?></td>
    <td><?= $IndexEstimate['client_first']?> <?= $IndexEstimate['client_last']?></td>
    <td><?= $IndexEstimate['total'] ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
</tbody>
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please provide the for loop? As far as I can predict, you are assigning only the last row retrieved to variable that is being looped over in your table.

Comment: My apologies, totally forgot to do so. @sitilge

Comment: Where does `$resultIndexEstimate` come from? Is it in any way connected to `$resultIndexInvoice`?

Comment: remove `$rowIndexInvoice = $resultIndexInvoice->fetch_assoc();` after `$resultIndexInvoice = $connect_db->query($queryIndexInvoice);`. This is selecting the 1st row, and then when you do `<?php while($IndexEstimate = $resultIndexEstimate->fetch_assoc()) {?>` it will begin from row 2.

Comment: `$resultIndexEstimate` still missing. Have you tried to var_dump it? You should to iterate over `$resultIndexInvoice`.

Comment: Again, my apologies, I copied over the wrong text, I made the necessary edits again @SiggiSv

Comment: Ah. Now it's clear that like @Sean said, the loop starts at 2nd row because 1st row had already been fetched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are calling `->fetch_assoc();` on your result set, before your loop, so when you get to the loop, your internal pointer is at the 2nd returned row. You need to remove `$rowIndexInvoice = $resultIndexInvoice->fetch_assoc();`

```
$resultIndexInvoice = $connect_db->query($queryIndexInvoice);
$rowIndexInvoice = $resultIndexInvoice->fetch_assoc(); <--Remove this line
$numIndexInvoice = $resultIndexInvoice->num_rows;
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know one fetch can effect the other. I always thought it was just fetching the rows all together and can be repeated again without any problems. Thanks guys for the clarification!

Comment: Your fetches are using the same result set - `$resultIndexInvoice`, so that is why the first fetch affects the second fetch. You can repeat fetching the rows from the beginning if you use [`$resultIndexInvoice->data_seek(0)`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php).